# Why are these people in Winterfell for so long?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

We see that for most (all?) of season 7 of *Game of Thrones*, the Stark bannermen and the Lord(s?) of the Vale are stationed in Winterfell.

Why? Don't they have their castles/holds to tend to?

In "Eastwatch" (*Game of Thrones*, S07E05), they complain that Jon "King in the North" Snow is not "in the north" to tend to his duties. Doesn't this also apply to them?

Comment: There is no evidence to suggest they are *always* there. It seems more reasonable to assume that they have monthly meetings. Understand that weeks can pass within an episode (consider Sansa's line: `I haven't heard from [Jon] in weeks`).

Comment: They are there waiting for the Night's King and Battle for Dawn II. They can't go home. If they do, how long will it take to reassemble once the real enemy is there? Dispersing your forces is a fatal mistake even against human foes as Edmure Tully learnt in starting days of War of the Five Kings.

Comment: @GhotiandChips It may be true for Northern Lords but Valemen can't be expected to take the long road to Vale and back every month or so in Winter Roads.

Comment: @Aegon I agree with that much. The Waynwoods are in charge of the Vale, now, though, as we see Arya and The Hound run into them at the bloody gate.

Comment: @OP, however, it must be noted Meera returns to Greywater Watch to be with her family when the Wall comes crashing down. Lord Reed and his family are at their home. Perhaps Northern Lords from nearby castles stay at their own castles as well. Their armies are peasants however, not standing modern armies. They come once their liege Lords call but it takes a lot of time to reassemble your levies again

Comment: @GhotiandChips but Littlefinger is always there. why would the Lords of the Vale go back, and leave him in Winterfell?

Comment: @Aegon but Lord Reed is never shown at the meetings, is he?

Comment: @Federico No he doesn't but that's just to show that not all Northern Lords are at Winterfell. Greywater Watch is near the Southern border of North, a long way from Winterfell. So it implies that distance factor must be noted. Some distant lords might not come at all. Some distant lords might prefer to stay at Winterfell

Comment: @Federico The man you see is Lord Royce. The people in charge of the Vale now is House Arryn (if you recall, Robin Arryn is being trained to fight and presumably being educated in a similar way Bran was (before Theon took Winterfell)). The Vale, then, is not at all abandoned, it's being run as planned, it's only Littlefinger and Lord Royce (and probably some troops, and maybe some other vassal lords) who are in Winterfell (this is probably to bolster the troops/garrison until the Starks can enlist an army of its own).

Comment: @Aegon feel free to turn your comments in an answer :)

Comment: @GhotiandChips you too ^^

Comment: ISTR Jon mentioned that the bannermen need to band together in Winterfell as it's the strongest stronghold and stands the strongest chance of withstanding the White Walkers.

Comment: With the Bloody Gate (where attackers have to go through a pass only wide enough for three across, according to Littlefinger), one doesn't need a full army garrisoned (unless you are fighting against dragons, but I don't see how it would help there, either) to hold the castle.  They could have taken the bulk of the Vale's forces, left behind a much smaller garrison, and still not be at risk.  Or, at least the cost-benefit of taking the Vale even from a small garrison wouldn't be worth the march and the losses.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet I'm not speaking only of defence, but also administration, it's not like the have the internet to work in remote.

Comment: @Federico - Remember when they were having the inquisition about Lady Lysa Arryn's death?  There were several of the Vale lords (two male, one female) there grilling LittleFinger and then Sansa.  Only Lord Royce traveled north with the Knights.  Clearly there are at least two capable administrators/leaders behind. Flip this around.  How is Winterfell functioning with its leader gone indefinitely? How did it function when Ned left to be Hand of Robert Baratheon? There are always subordinates and a chain of command.

Comment: I would really appreciate if downvoters would explain what's wrong with the posts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Update

While answering another question, I stumbled upon a part of the script that reveals more information.

In S07E03, [Sansa talks about the food stores of Winterfell](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=game-of-thrones&episode=s07e03):

(*Sansa in italics*)

> *How much do we have?*
>   - 4,000 bushels, my lady.
>   *What does that mean?*
>   - For the current occupants of the castle, it's enough food for a year, perhaps more.
>   *And what's the longest winter in the past hundred years?*
>   - Uh, I'm not entirely certain. I-I'll check Maester Luwin's records. He kept a copy of every raven scroll.
>   *You're telling me we don't have enough food, **especially not if the armies of the North come back** to defend Winterfell?*
>   - No, my lady, most likely not.

This means that at least a *significant* amount of the forces has actually returned home.
There might be small exceptions to this, e.g. a subset of the Knight of the Vale who have stayed behind with Littlefinger, who seems to be residing in Winterfell for now.

So it would stand to reason that the forces have gone back home, and the Lords simply return whenever a meeting is held.

---

### My original answer

Winter is here. There is no more time to lose. The Northmen are expecting an attack from the White Walkers at any time.

While this may be weeks or months, you need to observe how long it would take to reassemble the army if you let them disband for the time being. It would take weeks to get everyone back to Winterfell, fully armed and ready to go.

You need to distinguish between the lords and the armies here. An army is slow to mobilize, but a lord can travel more easily.

*(**edit** the following paragraph is wrong, see update)*
Instead, the **army** stays there, so that they can mobilize when needed. This also allows them to train. Since they are already feeling ill equipped to battle the Walkers' army, and they are essentially fighting for humanity, it stands to reason that they are training their men.
It has been mentioned a few times by Sansa that storing food for the future is a problem. But Winterfell is not besieged by any issues with its food production (at least, none are mentioned in the show). However, having a large army near Winterfell will make a sizeable dent in the food supplies, therefore depleting the food stores faster and requiring more food to be stored for winter.

However, about the **lords** staying in Winterfell, that could be different. It's possible that the lords return home inbetween meetings. There are considerable time gaps in the current season (Jon's travels seem to take no time, but he's traveling most of the continent. Compare that to Robert and Cersei's trip from King's Landing to Winterfell, which took **weeks** according to Cersei).

Then again, Littlefinger does appear to be staying there permanently. It's not impossible for some lords to stay in Winterfell, even if some others return home. This could correspond to how far they have to travel, or in Littlefinger's case, because he's gathering intel.

Comment: If a paragraph is wrong, delete it.